# VC++ 2008 Express MFC Download

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, wizard

I am following this tutorial:
http://www.generation5.org/content/2001/sr00.asp?Print=1

Right off the bat it asks me to use the MFC Application Wizard to create a new project. It turns out that it's not included with the Visual Studio 2008 Express.

Is there any way that I can download it so that I can use it to continue the tutorial? Or is would I just have to buy the standard version?

If I can't download it, what would I have to do in order to create the project myself manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe MFC is one of the things Microsoft removed from the free "Express" edition. There isn't a free download of MFC, so you would have to purchase the standard Visual Studio.

A quick look at the tutorial shows that it does indeed use MFC features, so there probably isn't an easy way to follow the tutorial *without* using MFC.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping this wasn't the case. If only VC++ standard wasn't so expensive.